# Elimination of try-catch block in async function with help of a wrapper function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, error-handling, higher-order-functions

Need help converting this function for react so onSubmit function could be catchErrors(onSubmit) and no try-catch blocks

This function works for express and could send errors to the next middleware:

```
exports.catchErrors = (fn) => {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    return fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
};
```

What do I want to achieve? 
Elimination of try-catch blocks in the onSubmit function

So the form tag would have something like `onSubmit={catchErrors(this.onSubmit)}` and there will be no try-catch block in onSubmit async function

Comment: That doesn't look like a higher order **component** but looks like expres handler that's wrapped. Your tagged this question wrong.

Comment: well yeah it goes under errorHandler.js and takes care of all the errors for async await so we could use those without try catch. I want something similar in react

Comment: You mean [error boundries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)?

Comment: No. I want to do something like onSubmit={catchErrors(this.onSubmit)} in the form and then getting rid of try catch in onSubmit which is an async function

Comment: It's really unclear what you want to do. Where did you get this function from? What does it have to do with react? There are no `req`, `res`, `next` on the client side. What do you expect to happen with an error, what handler should be called?

Comment: Let's just console.log the error for now. I am using this function for the backend side where I don't have to write try-catch block anymore in controller functions. Yeah I do know there's no req, res, next on the client side, so can't we just log the errors for now? I'm thinking of having multiple handling for different components and import it that way